# How to limit foreach loop

Tags: php

This is my foreach code

```
foreach ($response3["keywords"] as $genreObject) {
             $keywords_name = $genreObject["name"];
             $stmt->execute();
         }
```

Any better way to limit the loop without this?

```
if ($i++ == 10) break;
```

Comment: how about array_slice($array,0,10);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the actual array the loop iterates over:

```
<?php
foreach (array_slice($response3["keywords"], 0, 10) as $genreObject) {
    $keywords_name = $genreObject["name"];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Or, if the array is a straight numerically indexed one, you can use a `for` loop which is more efficient:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
    $keywords_name = $response3["keywords"][$i]["name"];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Oh, is the 1st method better than break statement?

Comment: @JohnDoo It is a questionable thing to speak of "good" or "bad" in programming. That judgement fully depends on what criteria you apply... The most important aspect _usually considered_ is readability, since that is what makes code worth reusing and maintaining.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find the lost of readability to not be a big deal when the code's documentation is well written. You could do this.

```
<?php
     $i=0;
     while($i<10 && $keyword = $response3["keywords"][$i++]; ) {
         $keywords_name = $keyword["name"];
         $stmt->execute();
     }
```

It doesn't look as neat as the `array_slice()` w/ foreach loop but that would result in a new array being made which doesn't really matter unless it's a particularly long and heavy script

Comment: Has to be `while($i<10 && .. )` although the same error is in the question. I am assuming that you want 10, not 11, because 10 is a round number.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it